# djangocms integration filer_image with apphook objects

Tags: django, tags, django-cms

I want to add `filer_image` field to my `Gift` class instance object. It works as apphook in django-cms. The main problem is that after making migrations and open the view where the form is I don't have loaded js.

I already added all tags:

```
{% load staticfiles i18n cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags thumbnail filer_tags filer_image_tags %}
```

The model is:

```
class Gift(models.Model):    
    filer_image = FilerImageField(related_name="book_covers")
```

The form:

```
class GiftForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'basic-input full-width'}),
        }
```

The rendered output:

[The thumbnail and input view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlroX.png)

Please tell me what am I doing wrong with these. It seems to me like some js files are not loaded. After click it opens `FileImageFiler` gallery, but I also cannot select any image.

Comment: Make sure you're including any javascript. `Forms` in django can have a `Media` class to include CSS & JS for their fields so you might be able to do `{{ form.media.js }}` to get a list of javascript files in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find the soliton. Basically I added {{ form.media }} after {{ csrf_token } and I have extended the form class with:

```
class Media:
    extend = False
    css = {
        'all': [
            'filer/css/admin_filer.css',
        ]
    }
    js = (
        'admin/js/core.js',
        'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js',
        'admin/js/jquery.init.js',
        'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js',
        'admin/js/actions.js',
        'admin/js/admin/urlify.js',
        'admin/js/prepopulate.js',
        'filer/js/libs/dropzone.min.js',
        'filer/js/addons/dropzone.init.js',
        'filer/js/addons/popup_handling.js',
        'filer/js/addons/widget.js',
        'admin/js/related-widget-wrapper.js',
    )
```

That is all!